# java application installation through .cab

Tags: java, .net

I have an application with a .jar installer.
the .jar file is the installer. Now i want to make a .cab file for the application and install it using internet explorer through web config. I got a tool by which i have converted my .jar installer into .exe now i want to convert it into .cab file which can be installed with .cab file

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Java has [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html) which allows you to run a Java application launched from any browser, instead of limiting you to IE.

Comment: its a requirement by a microsoft freak cllient

Answer (score 0):

I guess [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) can create these files if you need native windows installable files.

It also has a maven plugin.

Comment: we have an exe now we want to develop .cab app so that it can be downloaded on IE and installed